# How to check object structure in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, controller

I am working on a ruby application where i created a controller which accepts an object/array as parameter and process it to generate output but i am not getting the output in proper required format, object/array seems good when passed to controller but there must be some issues which is blocking the proper output but i am not getting how to debug it.

```
def duplicate
  for @job in @pipeline.jobs
    @Job.save
  end  
end
```

it tried to print the object structure but getting error.
i thought to use javascript console.log but dont know how to implement it inside controller.

is there any way to check the object/array structure or see output on screen.

Comment: look at `pry` or `byebug`

Comment: You can use `object.inspect` to get the object structure

Comment: I don't think having a controller that accepts an object is the Rails way of doing things. It seems like you're fighting/breaking Rails by doing so. If you do call `initialize` don't forget to call `super`.

Comment: Then what is the best way and what approach should i follow as a beginner.